# Override Doctrine Annotation Driver

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to make some changes in Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\Annotation::getAllClassNames because Doctrine use require_one and I want it to use my custom spl autoloader.

My Question is: How can I tell Doctrine to use my own code without changing Symfony's vendor folder?

Comment: the code of `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\Annotation::getAllClassNames` is not about autoloading, but about finding all files and requiring them.

Comment: yes, but it requires all and if one file is already required, php will throw a 'cannot redeclare xy' error

Comment: sorry, wrong explained. I have classes which are defined twice in different files, that is the problem here at require_once and the recursive iterator

Comment: you can always extend that driver, override that method and set an instance of your own class as mapping driver for your ORM instance... Where are you stuck at?

Comment: yes... but how to tell doctrine to use my mapping driver (outside the symfony vendor folder) instead of its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to achieve this by setting the parameter `doctrine.orm.metadata.annotation.class` to the name of your class in your parameters.ini/yml/xml.

From Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Resources/config/orm.xml:

```
 <parameter key="doctrine.orm.metadata.annotation.class">Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver</parameter>
```

I've not tested this myself, but this is how I've overriden things like this in the past.

Comment: sounds good, but when i try to add this to my yml (under doctrine -> orm) i get `Unrecognizes options "metadata" under "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I override Doctrine bundle's MappingDriver.
Nowdays (dec 2023) changing `doctrine.orm.metadata.annotation.class` is not an option, we need to use Symfony DC superpowers, here is working example:

```php
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\MappingDriver;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriver as MappingDriverInterface;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute;

#[Attribute\AsDecorator('.doctrine.orm.default_metadata_driver')]
final class DoctrineMappingDriverOverride extends MappingDriver implements MappingDriverInterface
{
    private MappingDriverInterface $driver;
    private ContainerInterface $idGeneratorLocator;

    public function __construct(
        #[Attribute\Autowire(service: '.doctrine.orm.default_metadata_driver.inner')]
        MappingDriverInterface $driver,
        #[Attribute\Autowire(service: 'doctrine.id_generator_locator')]
        ContainerInterface $idGeneratorLocator,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($driver, $idGeneratorLocator);
        $this->driver = $driver;
        $this->idGeneratorLocator = $idGeneratorLocator;
    }
}
```